# .NET 6.0 why trace listeners config is not working anymore?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I just created a new simple console app in VS2022 for .NET 6.0 - all default settings.

Then I added to project:

- package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
- app.config file

In app.config I put following code (just from standard example from microsoft):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
            <listeners>
                <clear/>
                <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
                <remove name="Default" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

In program.cs I have following code:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Diagnostics;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var x = new System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener();
Trace.WriteLine("abs-test");

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("--- {0} trace listeners", Trace.Listeners.Count));
int idx = 0;
foreach (TraceListener lsnr in Trace.Listeners)
{
    idx++;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  #{0}: {1}", idx, lsnr));
}

Console.WriteLine("ok...");
```

Then I run app and... TRACE LOG WAS NOT CREATED AT ALL!

So, no errors, it started and finished, but no trace output.
Also - in list of trace listeners I see only 1 element - "System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener".

It looks like .NET 6.0 app completely ignores any configuration in <system.diagnostics> section in app.config!
But why?!

How to make it working like it worked in .NET 2.x .. 4.x frameworks?!

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. There are no trace listeners in .NET Core. No `app.configr` or `web.config` eitehr

Comment: Instead of trying to replicate the old TraceListeners use the built-in [Logging middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). All libraries, applications and NuGet packages use this. Log providers like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) are ages ahead of what trace listeners were able to provide. Every observability vendor (eg Elastic, Datadog, Honeycomb, Microsoft) have an ILogger-compatible sink

Comment: But when I create System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener class explicitly in code - it exists. Also Trace.* object with all its properties and methods exists. So, it must be there. I do not believe it is not supported. Otherwise it must be marked as [Depreated] at least.
Also when I can create listeners manually from code - it works! So, only app.config is not working. But when I screw up XML structure of app.config - application cannot start at all, so it is loaded. Thus, your advise is not match what I see in reality.

Comment: In that case, how come there's no output? How come they aren't used in any of the .NET project templates? Just because the legacy classes exist doesn't mean they're actually used any more.

Comment: The app.config file [was](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/16332#issue-558050209) not considered by Trace on .NET core. Apparently it has been [added back in .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7716#issuecomment-1232209892). Not to sound snarky, but frankly it took only a couple of minutes to google/bing this ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already outlined in the comment above, .NET 6.0 did not consider the app.config file when initializing the Trace system.

So unless you manually read the app.config file (with or without using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(), etc.) and configure the Trace from that, there is no way this will happen in .NET 6.0.

The reason given in comments on GitHub is that, the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package [did not exist](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23937#issuecomment-339049116) in .NET Core at the time the System.Diagnostics.Trace* stuff was initially ported for .NET Core.

The functionality is available, starting with .NET 7.0. However, you need to manually ensure that initialization happens based on the app.config file. This is necessary, because nothing .NET (Core) causes the ConfigurationManager to be initialized automatically (by the runtime).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <clear/>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

The app.config is basically unchanged from your version.

Make sure that you add a reference to [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.nupkg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/7.0.0) at least in version *7.0.0* (the 6.x versions do not include the `TraceConfiguration` class).

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Diagnostics;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

// Initialize Trace configuration from app.config
TraceConfiguration.Register();

// ...
```

Note that you will not see any trace messages that are issued from code that runs before the `TraceConfiguration.Register()` line is executed. This could be the case if Trace is used from code that runs from static initialization.